# CSharpCodeProvider and obfuscation

Tags: c#, obfuscation, csharpcodeprovider

I would like to create a DLL dynamically in my Web Application which can generate a unique class (specifically a unique variable inside which is unique to this download) and then can be downloaded by the user.

I can do this with CSharpCodeProvider however I don't wish to reveal this key to anyone who reflects the DLL.

Is there a way I can obfuscate this value within the Assembly?

Comment: You do realize that all obfuscation does is to make reverse engineering somewhat harder, right? It doesn't make it impossible.

Comment: Yeah... I'm beginning to realise that, which I can do myself anyway when I generate the code